# How to convert a cv::mat header and data part into a single qbytearray?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qftp

I want to use `Qftp` module of Qt 4.8.1 to send opencv images to a FTP server. I wrote the following code:

```
        ftp = new QFtp(this);
        //ftp initilization
          .
          .
          .
          . 
        //
        cv::Mat InputImage(100,100,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar::all(75));
        QImage FTP_Result = QImage((const uchar *) InputImage.data, InputImage.cols, InputImage.rows, InputImage.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        QByteArray byteMe((char *) FTP_Result.bits());

        qDebug()<<"Image size is: "<<FTP_Result.height()<<"*"<<FTP_Result.width(); //it returns 100*100
        ftp->put(byteMe,"Sample.jpg");
```

When I go into the ftp server hard disk I find **Sample.jpg**, and it is filled with "K" character which is the Asci equivalent of "75". It seems the header is missing so the operating system thinks it is just a simple text file. I think this is because I only copied **InputImage.data** into the QByteArray variable so no information about the image is available. what should I do to copy "InputImage" header information into the "byteMe" variable so I could store a healthy JPEG file ?

Comment: When you store this image into your hard disk what do you see ? did you use .save or .fromdata method of QImage ?

Comment: @PsP Yeah I tested .save method but because I'm telling qt the image format in FORMAT argument of save method, it adds the header and I will store a healthy image in my hard disk. But I don't want to store the image in my hard disk. I want to store it in my FTP server hard disk

Comment: hmmm, did you try to use QImage instead of QByteArray ?

Comment: @PsP Yeah but it failed to write the image into the FTP server. the image size was 0 KB !!! so I used Qbytearray

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
QByteArray byteMe((char *) FTP_Result.bits(), FTP_Results.byteCount());
```

When you construct with a simple `char *` its going to look for a null terminated string.